# How to set default value to the field and disable other fields if default value is selected in angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

I have the following fields- country, state, city, center.

The default value for all the fields is "All".

I am able to enable the fields one by one by using selection of previous field value.

But it is not considering "All" as a value. If it considers then the state is getting activated. So can anyone please help me how to set default value as "All" to all the fields and if "All" is selected then the other fields should be disabled with considering "All" as a value.

**My HTML Page :**

```
<div class="col-sm-2 sidenav" style="height:850px;">
      <div class="well">
      <form class="form-row " role="form">
      <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label col-sm-14" for="fName">Country*</label>
          <select class="form-control" ng-model="model.selectedCountry" name="country" ng-change="GetCountry(model.selectedCountry)"> 
               <!--<option value class selected>ALL</option>-->
               <option ng-repeat="item in model.countries track by $index" value="{{item}}">{{item}}</option>
                   </select>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label col-sm-20" for="fName">State*</label>
          <select class="form-control" ng-model="model.selectedState" name="state" ng-change="GetState(model.selectedState)" ng-disabled="!model.selectedCountry"> 
               <!--<option value class selected>ALL</option>-->
               <option ng-repeat="item in model.states track by $index" value="{{item}}">{{item}}</option>
                   </select>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label col-sm-20" for="fName">City*</label>
          <select class="form-control" ng-model="model.selectedCity" name="city" ng-change="GetCity(model.selectedCity)"  ng-disabled="!model.selectedState"> 
               <!--<option value class selected>ALL</option>-->
               <option ng-repeat="item in model.cities track by $index" value="{{item}}">{{item}}</option>
                   </select>
          </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-sm-20" for="fName">Center*</label>
                        <select class="form-control" ng-model="model.selectedCenter" name="center" ng-change="GetCenter(model.selectedCenter)" ng-disabled="!model.selectedCity">
                        <!--<option value class selected>ALL</option>-->
               <option ng-repeat="item in model.centers track by $index" value="{{item}}">{{item}}</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label col-sm-20" for="fName">Role*</label>
          <select class="form-control" ng-model="model.selectedRole" name="city" ng-change="GetRole(model.selectedRole)"  ng-disabled="!model.selectedCountry"> 
               <!--<option value class selected>ALL</option>-->
               <option ng-repeat="item in model.roles track by $index" value="{{item}}">{{item}}</option>
                   </select>
          </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" href="#" ng-click="HeadCount()" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" ng-hide="submitButton" ng-disabled="!model.selectedRole">SUBMIT</button>
                    </div>
            </form>
        </div>  
    </div>
```

Comment: Here "All" is also a value in your dropdown right? Then  ng-disabled="!model.selectedCountry"  will return false. so the next dropdown is enabled. isn't it?

Comment: Use one more boolean variable for ng-disabled.  Give 'true' or 'false' value to that variable based on your condition in the method which is called at the 'ng-change'

Comment: Another boolean ng-disable? can u please explain in detail

Answer (score 1):

Hi check this https://plnkr.co/edit/4Vc5EG7BXKikKGp0EdKe

for default selection

```
$scope.CategoryLst = [
  { id: '0', name: 'ALL' },
    { id: '1', name: 'MD' },
    { id: '2', name: 'CRNA' },
    ];

   $scope.item =$scope.CategoryLst[0]
```

**HTML**

```
 <select ng-model="item" ng-options="i.name for i in CategoryLst" ng-change="citychange()" ></select>
```

while onchange disabled the other select filed you can check based on id or Name

```
$scope.citychange = function()
    {
     if($scope.item.id == "0")
     {
       $scope.disabledflag = true
     };
    }
```

Comment: I had already set the default value = "ALL".                                 But I want how to disable the field if the previous field value is "ALL" and need to use that value "ALL".

Answer (score 0):

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="model.selectedCountry" name="country" ng-change="GetCountry(model.selectedCountry)"> 
           <!--<option value class selected>ALL</option>-->
           <option ng-repeat="item in model.countries track by $index" value="{{item}}">{{item}}</option>
               </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-20" for="fName">State*</label>
      <select class="form-control" ng-model="model.selectedState" name="state" ng-change="GetState(model.selectedState)" ng-disabled="!model.selectedCountry"> 
           <!--<option value class selected>ALL</option>-->
           <option ng-repeat="item in model.states track by $index" value="{{item}}">{{item}}</option>
               </select>
      </div>
```

Here, You can add another variable for ng-disabled,

> ```
>   <select class="form-control" ng-model="model.selectedState" name="state" ng-change="GetState(model.selectedState)" ng-disabled="disableState">
> ```

And in your Controller you can add,

```
$scope.GetState=function(arg){
$scope.disableState=false;
if(model.selectedCountry=="All"){
model.selectedState="All";
$scope.disableState=true;
}

// Your logic for this function may go here

}
```

You need to add the following line at your initialization part in your controller..

```
$scope.disableState=false;
```

Comment: State and city gets enabled. Country it considering the value as All and state gets enabled. state is not getting disabled and considering the default value All