# Angularjs disable submit button after submitted and enable if any change done in form

Tags: html, angularjs

I need to disable the submit button when it is clicked, and to enable it when any change is made to the form.

#### HTML

```html
<div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" href="#" ng-click="HeadCount()" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" ng-hide="submitButton" ng-disabled="!model.selectedRole">SUBMIT</button>
</div>
```

In this code, I am calling a function when the submit button is clicked.

#### Controller

My controller which disables my submit button when it is clicked once:

```
$scope.HeadCount = function() {      
    console.log("headcount");
    $scope.showGraph = !$scope.showGraph;
    $scope.submitButton = true;

    if ($scope.showGraph) {
            /* rest of my code which show the result image */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled

You have even example in there :P

HTML:

```
<label>Click me to toggle: <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked"></label><br/>
<button ng-model="button" ng-disabled="checked">Button</button>
```

JS:

```
it('should toggle button', function() {
  expect(element(by.css('button')).getAttribute('disabled')).toBeFalsy();
  element(by.model('checked')).click();
  expect(element(by.css('button')).getAttribute('disabled')).toBeTruthy();
});
```

You can also use `$watch()` to check if form scope is changing, and then enable button.

EDIT:
You might also want to check ngChange and ngInit in manual:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit